# AutoLink to call activity : Android

Tags: android, textview, android-xml

I have two activities say `JoinTeam` and `CreateTeam`.
`JoinTeam` has `UI` which has a `link` to `CreateTeam`.
Can we give `path` of the `CreateTeam` in `autolink`?
Any help will be great.

Comment: U mean u wanna redirect to CreateTeam activity?

Comment: yes, I want to move to CreateTeam if user clicks the link.

Comment: so y dont u use onClick event and redirect via Intent?

Comment: I am just thinking to have another easy solution.

Comment: whats That ???? if u know solution then y question?

Comment: say we set android:autoLink = "createActivity" and in string.xml we give the path.

Comment: every language has their unique way and you are talking about the html way ... IN android you have to use intent like link in html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
textview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View viewIn) {
                 Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreateTeam.class);

    startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

> Or
>
> in XML file
>
> u can use onClick Attribute and redirect to function u want .